# How to map one-to-many connection between two entities using a 3rd table, in Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, orm

I have two entities, `User` and `Event`. Each event can have multiple users associated with it, so its a one to many between Event and User.

The way its being stored in the database, is that I have 3 tables, `user, event, and event_user`. `event_user` contains 3 fields, `id, eventId, userId`. So I can do a query like `select userId from event_user where eventId = ?` to get all the users which are associated with the event.

My question is, how can I map this relationship between the events and users in Hibernate, to get it to auto save/load the users associated with the event? I want to have the following field in the Event class:

`Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();`

and have hibernate auto load / save the users to this set.

How can I map this (using annotations)?

Comment: Are you sure the cardinality of the relationship is one to many?  It sounds like it is modeled as a many to many in the database.  Couldn't a user attend more than one event?

Comment: @KevinBowersox Yes, you're right. Its a many to many. However the `User` entity class doesn't have a field referring to the events. Only the `Event` class has a field referring to the users. So as far as hibernate is concerned, it can be mapped as a one to many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the @ManyToMany annotation.

```
class Event{

    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "EVENT_USER", 
               joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "EVENT_ID") }, 
               inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID") })
    private Set<Users> users = new HashSet<Users>();

}
```

For more information on many to many associations in JPA check out this [video tutorial at my blog](http://blog-tothought.rhcloud.com/post/10).

Comment: I don't want to have a field in `User` referencing the events. Can this be done without that?

Comment: It is not required.  I just added it to demonstrate how to make the relationship bidirectional.

Comment: Could you update your answer to show how to do this with just having a field in `Event` and not having anything in `User`?

Comment: Any chance you could take a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22451382/how-to-map-one-to-many-connection-between-two-entities-using-a-3rd-table-in-hib

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate doc on the [Bidirectional mapping using annotations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html#collections-bidirectional) should help

Basically you need to do something like this

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {
    @ManyToMany(
        targetEntity=org.hibernate.test.metadata.manytomany.Event.class,
        cascade={CascadeType.ALL}
    )
    @JoinTable(
        name="USER_EVENT",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="USER_ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="EVENT_ID")
    )
    public Set<Event> getEvents() {
        return events;
    }
    ...
}              
@Entity
public class Event implements Serializable {
    @ManyToMany(
        cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},
        mappedBy = "events",
        targetEntity = User.class
    )
    public Set<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to create a field in my `User` class referring to the events. Is that necessary for this?

Comment: You need to have fields for each other. Without field, you may need to write query

Comment: @sanbhat Cascading the persist on both entities will cause issues, it creates an infinite loop.

Comment: @KevinBowersox thanks, I dint know that. Basically I directed the OP to a similar approach. In the document, they also have given updating the entities, which OP also wanted to explore